# Foreach is skipping some fields

Tags: php

My foreach is skipping some fields, and I don't know why but it's skipping the fields that in my DB are `False` this is my code:

```
            $sql2="SELECT     Card.*
                    FROM         Person INNER JOIN
                    Card ON Person.PersonUId = Card.PersonUId
                    WHERE Card.PersonUId = '$id'
                    ORDER BY CardNr ASC";
            $stm2 = $conn->query($sql2);

            if(!$stm2)
            {
                echo "";
            }else{
            $rowsCabeçalho = $stm2->fetch();
                    $CType = isset($rowsCabeçalho['CardType']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['CardType'] : NULL;
                    $CNr = isset($rowsCabeçalho['CardNr']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['CardNr'] : NULL;
                    $CValFrom = isset($rowsCabeçalho['ValidFrom']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['ValidFrom'] : NULL;
                    $CValUntil = isset($rowsCabeçalho['ValidUntil']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['ValidUntil'] : NULL;
                    $CLTCCNr = isset($rowsCabeçalho['LastTccNr']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['LastTccNr'] : NULL;
                    $CLTCCTime = isset($rowsCabeçalho['LastTccTime']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['LastTccTime'] : NULL;
                    $CIOEntryOff = isset($rowsCabeçalho['IoCheckEntryOff']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['IoCheckEntryOff'] : NULL;
                    $CIOExitOff = isset($rowsCabeçalho['IoCheckExitOff']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['IoCheckExitOff'] : NULL;
                    $CICoded = isset($rowsCabeçalho['IsCoded']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['IsCoded'] : NULL;
                    $CCodingDate = isset($rowsCabeçalho['CodingDate']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['CodingDate'] : NULL;
                    $CPrice = isset($rowsCabeçalho['Price']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['Price'] : NULL;
                    $CPricePyed = isset($rowsCabeçalho['PricePayed']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['PricePayed'] : NULL;
                    $CDeposit = isset($rowsCabeçalho['Deposit']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['Deposit'] : NULL;
                    $CDepositPayed = isset($rowsCabeçalho['DepositPayed']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['DepositPayed'] : NULL;
                    $CLastCCode = isset($rowsCabeçalho['LastLicenseCountryCode']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['LastLicenseCountryCode'] : NULL;
                    $CLastLPlate = isset($rowsCabeçalho['LastLicensePlate']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['LastLicensePlate'] : NULL;
                    $CIOOffNextUse = isset($rowsCabeçalho['IoCheckOffNextUse']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['IoCheckOffNextUse'] : NULL;
                    $CLastEntryTime = isset($rowsCabeçalho['LastEntryTime']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['LastEntryTime'] : NULL;
                    $CLastExitTime = isset($rowsCabeçalho['LastExitTime']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['LastExitTime'] : NULL;
                    $CLastPTime = isset($rowsCabeçalho['LastPayTime']) ? $rowsCabeçalho['LastPayTime'] : NULL;

                    echo '
                    <div class="informaltable">
        <p></p>
        <table cellspacing="2" border="0">

            <thead>
                <tr>';?>
<?php 

$tableHeaders = [
  ['variable' => 'CType', 'title' => 'Tipo'],
  ['variable' => 'CNr', 'title' => 'Nr.'],
  ['variable' => 'CValFrom', 'title' => 'Válido Desde'],
  ['variable' => 'CValUntil', 'title' => 'Válido Até'],
  ['variable' => 'CLTCCNr', 'title' => 'Nº Último Terminal'],
  ['variable' => 'CLTCCTime', 'title' => 'Hora no Último Terminal'],
  ['variable' => 'CIOEntryOff', 'title' => 'IO na Entrada OFF'],
  ['variable' => 'CIOExitOff', 'title' => 'IO na Saída OFF'],
  ['variable' => 'CICoded', 'title' => 'Codificado'],
  ['variable' => 'CCodingDate', 'title' => 'Data de Codificação'],
  ['variable' => 'CPrice', 'title' => 'Valor'],
  ['variable' => 'CPricePyed', 'title' => 'Valor Pago'],
  ['variable' => 'CDeposit', 'title' => 'Depósito'],
  ['variable' => 'CDepositPayed', 'title' => 'Depósito Pago'],
  ['variable' => 'CLastCCode', 'title' => 'Último País de Matricula'],
  ['variable' => 'CLastLPlate', 'title' => 'Última Matricula'],
  ['variable' => 'CIOOffNextUse', 'title' => 'IO Off Na Próxima Saída'],
  ['variable' => 'CLastEntryTime', 'title' => 'Última Entrada'],
  ['variable' => 'CLastExitTime', 'title' => 'Última Saída'],
  ['variable' => 'CLastPTime', 'title' => 'Último Pagamento'],
];

foreach($tableHeaders as $tableHeader) : 
  $variable = $tableHeader['variable'];
  if (isset($$variable) AND !is_null($$variable) AND !empty(trim($$variable))) :
?>
  <th align="right"><?= $tableHeader['title']; ?></th>
<?php
  endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

This is the SS of the fields `$CIOEntryOff` which is in db `IoCheckEntryOff` and `$CIOExitOff` which is in db `IoCheckExitOff.

[image: DB Screenshot]

When I reaches on my foreach and start pacing the `<th align="right"><?= $tableHeader['title']; ?></th>` somehow it skips those two lines as you can see on this screenshot: [image: SS of how it should appear and how it appear]

Can someone help me with this, I don't know where is the error when it just skips those `False` fields, since when I set them to `True` they appear, but when they are `False` they don't.

Comment: `$$variable`  or `$variable`?

Comment: @Nawin Variable variables. Isn't it just the `!empty` check excluding the nulls?

Comment: I highly suggest that you rethink using variable variables.

Comment: @Nawin it needs to be `$$variable` or it will just send everything to the screen.

Comment: Haha I know @ficuscr, I run his code, When i place `$$variable` it shows empty., That's why i ask is this is typo or not?

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server?  It looks like the question is 100% PHP.

Comment: @Brian just tagged because I'm using sql server, but if it's not the problem let me remove.

Comment: @Nawin not sure I follow you. Empty like trying to echo null or not present in get_defined_vars()?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try and remove the `empty` check in the loop?
Far as I can see your condition excludes the columns with bool false values. Remember `empty(0) === true` and `empty(false) === true`.

```
<?php foreach($tableHeaders as $tableHeader): 
  $variable = $tableHeader['variable'];
  if (isset($$variable) && !is_null($$variable)): ?>
    <th align="right"><?= $tableHeader['title']; ?></th>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

**Update**

Does this maybe help? Think about order of precedent, maybe break it out from being a single line `if`. This should help you debug it.

```
<?php
$a = ['bool false' => false,
      'empty string' => '',
      'zero' => 0,
      'null' => null,
      'actual value' => '123'
     ];

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {      
    if ($v === 0) {
        echo "$k ($v) -> ZERO";
    } elseif ($v === false) {
        echo "$k ($v) -> FALSE";
    } elseif (is_null($v)) {
        echo "$k ($v) -> NULL";
    } elseif (empty($v)) {
        echo "$k ($v) -> EMPTY STRING";
    } else {
        echo "$k ($v) -> SOME VALUE";
    }       
}

> bool false () -> FALSE
> empty string () -> EMPTY STRING
> zero (0) -> ZERO
> null () -> NULL
> actual value (123) -> SOME VALUE
```

Comment: by doing it the fields appear and also appear the ones that are `NULL` in db and those ones should not appear

Comment: I've updated my answer, again, we are trying to address the `false` values, not the ones in a null state. I added back the `is_null`. Try it again.

Comment: My bad @ficuscr after checking again the fields that are appearing and should not appear are two of them as `0` (zero) in DB and the other one has `False`, Null ones are not appearing with your updated code.

Comment: *"Null ones are not appearing with your updated code"...* Wonder if it has anything to do with `!is_null($$variable)`?

Comment: When removing the `!is_null($$variable)` I get the same results with only the `isset($$variable)`, So I just need to remove the False values and the fields that have empty spaces, that's why I was using the `!empty(trim($$variable))` to remove the spaces of the tables that don't have anything on it just spaces

Comment: Gotcha. So you just need to be a bit more explicit... Let's see, in discerning between empty string and bool false?

Comment: Yes, the values that are False should not appear, the ones that have empty spaces should not appear, the ones that are Zero can appear.

Comment: But at the moment the only thing missing is the ones that have empty spaces.

Comment: The` !empty(trim($$variable))` also removes the ones that have Zero and that should not happen, it should just removes the ones that are on my DB with `spaces`

Comment: So, what is another way to check for an empty string, that would not include 0 as meeting criteria? You could check first explicitly for `=== 0` or you could change your check to do a `strlen`. I'm really hoping that with last update to answer you should be able to understand. Let me know if still not getting it. Almost there!

Comment: I still could not make it work, could not remove the ones with spaces, without broke the rest of the code

Comment: Wanna take this to chat or something? Your comments are not adding anything to the discussion. Saying "broke the rest" tells me nothing. Be specific, in speech, and even more so in code!

Comment: By using this: `if (isset($$variable) && !is_null($$variable) && !empty($$variable)):` or `if (isset($$variable) && !is_null($$variable) && !empty(trim($$variable))):` it removes the fields that have the value `0` (zero), and they should not be removed. I need a way to just remove the ones that appear because in the DB they have empty spaces on them.

Comment: `if (isset($$variable) && $$variable === 0 || (isset($$variable) && !is_null($$variable) && !empty($$variable))):`